# How do I set up a private mirror server for Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, mirror

I want to download all of the cygwin files for a computer that is not connected to the Internet. I know I can download all of the cygwin files with rsync, but I'm not quite sure of the right incantation. Can you help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I really am just guessing, but I suspect it might look something like this.

```
rsync --archive --verbose --delete cygwin.com::cygwin-ftp/ /your/local/path/
```

See: http://sourceware.org/cygwin-apps/package-server.html